# How come $ a \equiv b \pmod H$ when $ab^{-1} \in H$ and $H \subset G$?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

First of all, I'm not sure I understand what (mod X) is, as I'm only familiar with the modulo operation that doesn't contain parantheses. However, I believe I've described how it works below:

$$ a \equiv b \pmod H \implies a\equiv r \bmod H, \quad b \equiv r \bmod H $$

Basically, *a* and *b* have the same remainder when divided  by the modulus.

However, this setting is a bit different. Here, the modulus is a group (specifically a sub-group). Now, how a group can be a modulus is unknown to me, but I suspect it may be the group's order that is the modulus.  Furthermore, [this site](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_group_theory/Part_2_Subgroups_and_cyclic_groups) stated something and (to my knowledge) didn't prove it.

$$H \subset G, \quad a,b \in H$$
$$a \equiv b \pmod H \ \ \text{if} \ \ ab^{-1} \in H$$

First of all, there is no *if*:

If $\ b \in H \ \ $ then $ \ \ b^{-1} \in H$ [inverse]

If $\ a,b^{-1} \in H \ \ $ then $ \ \ ab^{-1} \in H$ [closure]

That means the above statement is not a conditional one, but a necessity. As such, it can be generalized to this:

$$\forall a,b, \in G, a\equiv b \pmod G$$

So, every element in a group is congruent to any element within that group, when using that group as a modulus? If this is correct, I would like a proof and an explanation for how a group can be a modulus. If this is incorrect, I'd like to know what is actually meant by the statement from the article.

Comment: As @Infinity_hunter notes in an answer, this is the _definition_ of what "mod" means for a general subgroup. The name was chosen since it generalizes what  "mod" means in the integers.

Comment: Another remark.  $a \equiv b \pmod H$ means, in terms of cosets, $Ha = Hb$, which is obviously an equivalence relation.

Comment: Part 1) One of the confusing thing about learning group theory the very first time is the simplest groups you first learn is integer addition where that binary operation is $+$ and the identity element is $0$ and the inverse of $a$ is $-a$ but we immediate go to *abstraction* and use the **notation** of *multiplication* we the binary operation is $\cdot$ the identity element is $1$ and the inverse of $a$ is $a^{-1}$.  But this is okay because it is *notation* and the addition works as a group operation on integers (modulus or not) regardless of the notation. but.....

Comment: Part 2)  If we consider the modulo addition definition of $a \equiv b \pmod n$ meaning $a-b = k\times n$  for some integer $n$ which in turn means $a-b \in n\mathbb Z$ where $n\mathbb Z$ is the group $\{..., -3n,-2n,-n,0,n,2n,....\}, + $, and if we put this in abstract group notation where $a-b = a + (-b) \mapsto ab^{-1}$ and $n\mathbb Z\mapsto H$ then *definition* of $a\equiv b \pmod H$ means $ab^{-1} \equiv e \pmod H$ means that $ab^{-1}\in H$ is ... similar.

Comment: Side comment. It is common (but, as you've illustrated, perhaps confusing) in mathematics to use *if* in definitions where it is intended to mean *iff*. Using $G$ in the equivalence relation is like using $m=1$ when you talk about integers mod $m$.

Comment: @fleablood Not sure I understand you. Isn't $\mapsto$ used to show the definition of a function, i.e. $f : x \mapsto x^2$? How is $a-b = a + (-b)$ a function?

Comment: I'm not doing math....I'm doing english....I just mean $\mapsto$ to mean $a-b$ is in addition notation to $ab^{-1}$ in generic group notation. That I used "$\mapsto$" was just the most convenient notation I could think of. (Although it *could* be seen as a function: The domain is {expressions about a group using addition as binary operation} and the co-domain is {expressions about a group using generic binary operation}.   If we have "$a+b = 0$" that means "$b$ operated on $a$ results in the identity" and that would be "mapped to" the expression "$ab = 1$".  That *is* a function... of sorts).

Comment: Be mindful that when $H$ is not normal, one does not usually use this notation, because there are two separate notions: "congruent modulo $H$ on the right" and "congruent modulo $H$ on the left": the first makes $a\equiv b$ if and only if $ab^{-1}\in H$, as you are doing; the second is defined as $a\equiv b$ if and only if $a^{-1}b\in H$. If $H$ is not normal, *they are not the same equivalence relation*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they are defining a relation on group $G$ using the subgroup $H$. It tells that $a,b$ are related if $ab^{-1} \in H$ and this is denoted as $a \equiv b \pmod H$.

When they define $\equiv$ it is written as

> $H \subset G, \quad a,b \in H ,a \equiv b \pmod H \ \ \text{if} \ \
>   ab^{-1} \in H$

Mostly here they mean $a,b \in G$ instead of $H$ (may be a typo) because if $a,b \in H$ then already $ab^{-1} \in H$.Also see that in  further equations $a,b$ are taken from $G$.

Comment: But that would mean that all elements of G are related, because every grouping of elements with G exist, and H is just one of them.

Comment: @ChemLad No. For example,  when $H$ is the subgroup of the even integers, $a \equiv b \mod H$ just when $a-b$ is even, so $a$ and $b$ have the same parity.

Comment: But isn't saying $a,b \in G, \ \ a \equiv \pmod H \ $ if $ \ ab^{-1} \in H$ the same as saying $a,b \in G, a \equiv \pmod H \ $ if $ \ ab \in H$? Surely the latter is quicker and cleaner? Saying that $a,b^{-1} \in H$ conveys the same amount of information as $a,b \in H$. What exactly is the relation between the fact that *a* and *b* share a remainder when divided by H and the fact that *a* and the inverse of *b* are within the group H.

Comment: @ChemLad I am not able to understand your last comment. Can you clarify what you mean by $a \equiv \pmod H$?

Comment: There was supposed to be a *b* there, sorry. $a,b∈G,  a≡ b \pmod H$

Comment: As noted by others this is a generalization of $ \mod .  $ operation in integers. Here the group operation is denoted by $\cdot$ and inverse of $b$ by $b^{-1}$. If you replace $\cdot$ by $+$ then the same definition can be written as $a \equiv b \pmod H$ if $a-b \in H$ which makes pretty sense.

Comment: $a \equiv b \pmod H \ $ if $ \ a-b \in H$ still doesn't make sense to me, probably because I don't understand what it means for a group to be a modulus. How can a group divide something? Or is there no division going on here?

Comment: @ChemLad  There is no division going on here. It is a **definition**  of a **relation** given by the resource that you are reading. Mostly they are using $\pmod H$ to make a reference to the particular subgroup $H$. If you change the subgroup you totally get a different relation. I have seen other textbooks on the group theory in which they introduce this concept somewhat differently.

Comment: If the relation isn't that *a* and *b* have the same remainder when divided by H, then what is the relation? Also, why use mod to show this entirely different relation, isn't that begging for confusion?

Comment: What do you mean by divided by $H$? There is only one operation in the group. $\qquad$If these notations causing confusion then you are free not to use them or consult a different source or even use a notation of your own, my point is that as far as you understand the concept,  the notations do not matter much.

Comment: @ChemLad: The condition $a\sim b\iff ab\in H$ is not an equivalence relation: it need not be reflexive (you would have $a\sim a\iff a^2\in H$, which need not happen in general); it need not be symmetric (just because $ab\in H$ you cannot conclude that $ba\in H$); and it need not be transitive (from $ab\in H$ and $bc\in H$, you cannot generally conclude that $ac\in H$). By contrast, the relation $a\sim b\iff ab^{-1}\in H$ is *necessarily* an equivalence relation, provided only that $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: @Chemlad: "If the relation isn't that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $H$"... This is a group. You cannot "divide by $H$", and there is no notion of "remainder". "same remainder when divided by $H$" is, literally, nonsense.

Comment: "just because $ab∈H$ you cannot conclude that $ba∈H$". I thought the closure principle meant that any combination of the elements must exist within the group. Or generalized, $a,b,c \in G \iff ab,ac,ba,bc,ca,cb \in G$ along with all powers of every element (this is all in the case of a group with multiplication as an operation). As such, any two elements within a group can be said to have an equivalence relation, no? Also, so if I understand correctly, the mod notation is simply used to show equivalence? It has nothing to do with the modulo operation other than that they both show equivalence?

Comment: Forgot to tag you @ArturoMagidin. See the above comment. An addendum to that comment is that under closure, $abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba \in G$.

Comment: @ChemLad: If $a,b\in H$, then both $ab$ and $ba$ are in $H$. *But that is not what is happening here.* You have a group $G$, and a *generally* **smaller** subgroup $H$. The elements $a$ and $b$ are in $G$, but need not be individually in $H$. For a very simple example, take $G=S_3$ and $H=\{e,(12)\}$. Now let $a=(123)$, $b=(23)$. Then $ab=(123)(23) = (12)\in H$ (composition right to left). But $ba=(23)(123)=(13)\notin H$. Note that neither $a$ nor $b$ are in $H$, $ab$ is in $H$, but $ba$ is **not** in $H$.

Comment: @ChemLad: Also, $a,b,c\in G$ implies $ab$, $ac$, $ba$, $bc$, $ca$, $cb\in G$, etc. But the converse implication need not hold. For example, if $a,b,c$ are all rationals equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, then all their "products" you list (i.e., sum, because that's the group operation) lies in $G=\mathbb{Z}$, even though none of them are in $\mathbb{Z}$ **individually**. That's another major misunderstanding you seem to be carrrying around.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Of course, if the elements are in the group, then the products of the elements must be in the group, but this doesn't necessarily go the other way, since the products of elements may be in the group, but not the elements themselves. This was the assumption I made that caused all the confusion. Thanks for clearing that up! Just a side question (it is just auxilliary, since I got the point), but what kind of operation are you doing when $(123)(23) = 12$?

Comment: @ChemLad: these are permutations written in cycle notation, and I am performing composition from right to left. $(23)$ is the permutation that fixes $1$ and exchanges $2$ and $3$. $(123)$ is the permutation that sends $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, and $3$ to $1$. If you compose them by doing $(23)$ first and $(123)$ second you get the permutation that exchanges $1$ and $2$ and fixes $3$, i.e., $(12)$.

Answer (score 1):

There's little to prove about
$$a\equiv b\pmod H\iff ab^{-1}\in H$$
because that is literally the *definition* of equivalence modulo $H$.

---

We can however relate this to the number theoretic
$$a\equiv b \pmod n\iff a\bmod n=b\bmod n$$
(were the *operation* "$\!\bmod n$" = taking the remainder after division by $n$ is used to defein the *relation* "$\equiv \pmod n$")
by observing that having the same remainder after division by $n$ is equivalent to $n$ dividing the difference, i.e.,
$$a\equiv b \pmod n\iff n\mid a-b.$$
If we rewrite the latter as $a-b\in n\Bbb Z$, we obtain for the subgroup $H:=n\Bbb Z$ of the group $G:=\Bbb Z$ that
$$ a\equiv b\pmod H\iff a-b\in H.$$
And now replace the additive notation used in $\Bbb Z$ with multiplicative notation as used in general group theory ...