# Is there an equivalence between $a$ and $b$ when $ab \in H$, $H \subset G$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, equivalence-relations, fake-proofs

$$ab \in H \iff a \equiv b \pmod H$$

It abides by reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.

**Proof of reflexivity:** (taken from [this site](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_group_theory/Part_2_Subgroups_and_cyclic_groups))

$H \subset G \\ a,e \in G \\ e = aa^{-1} \in H$

**Proof of symmetry:**

$ab \in H \\ (ab)^2 \in H \\ a^{-1}(ab)^2b^{-1} = a^{-1}(abab)b^{-1} \in H = (a^{-1}a)ba(bb^{-1}) \in H = ebae \in H = ba \in H$

**Proof of transitivity:**

$ab, bc \in H \\ abbc \in H \\ abb^{-1}b^{-1}bc \in H = aeec \in H = ac \in H$

However, I was told in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247605/how-come-a-equiv-b-pmod-h-when-ab-1-in-h-and-h-subset-g) that if $ab$ is in a group, it does not mean that $a$ is equivalent to $b$ in that group. However, it seems to me that the three criteria for equivalence has been met. What is correct?

**EDIT:**

Apparently, for the equivalence relation between $a$ and $b$ to be reflexive, both $a$ and $b$ must be equivalent to themselves (respectively) within the sub-group (if I understand correctly). Now, for something to be equivalent to itself is easy, because it is equal to itself, and equality is an equivalence. So, isn't the relation between $a$ and $b$ reflexive?

Comment: I am afraid that all three of your proofs are wrong, and this relation does not satisfy any of the three conditions. For example, to prove reflexitivity, you would  need to prove $a^2 \in H$ for all $a \in G$, which is clearly false in general.

Comment: @DerekHolt Could you elaborate? Why would one have to prove that $a^2 \in H \ \forall a  \in G$ to prove the reflexivity of $a \in H$, and why is this clearly false in general?

Comment: You would have to prove that $a^2 \in H$ for all $a \in G$, because that is exactly  what it means for the relation that you have defined to be reflexive. I think you should able to find an example of a group $G$ with a subgroup $H$ and an element $a \in G$ with $a^2 \not\in H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am not quite sure what it means for a relation to be reflexive (which is why I took my supposed proof from a site instead of trying to make it). However, for a value to be reflexive simply means that it is equal to itself. I thought that for a relation to be reflexive, it meant that the elements within the relation were equal to themselves, respectively. Basically, $a \equiv b \iff a = a \land b = b$. But this isn't what it means for a relation to be reflexive, then?

Comment: A relation $\equiv$ on a set $S$  is defined to be reflexive if $a \equiv a$ for all $a \in S$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I just realized what it means for a relation to be reflexive, and thus understood why $a^2$ is involved. However, isn't $a^2 \in H \ \forall a \in G$ true, just like $a^{-1} \in H \ \forall a \in G$. For every $a \in G$, if that *a* is in H, it's inverse will be there too, thus allowing the reflexivity of the relation between *a* and *b* when $ab^{-1} \in H$. However, for every $a \in G$, if that *a* is in H, every power of that *a* will also be in H, due to the closure law. Am I misunderstanding the "for every a" aspect of this?

Comment: @ChemLad Let $G$ be the cyclic group of order $3$ and $H$ the trivial subgroup. for example.

Comment: You twice wrote "for every $a \in G$, if that $a$ is in $H$", but you have to prove this property for all $a \in G$, not just those that also lie in $H$.

Comment: Okay, so for there to be reflexity of the relation between *a* and *b* when $ab \in H$, then the square of every element in G must be present in H. I have to questions: 1. Why? Why isn't it enough that the squares of the elements in H are present in H? 2. How is it true then that when $ab^{-1} \in H \implies a^{-1} \in H \ \forall a \in G \land b^{-1} \in H \ \forall a \in G$. In that instance, it works, but when the exponent is $2$, then it doesn't work. What's the difference? @DerekHolt

Comment: @user10354138 What is the operation of the cyclic group of order 3? I see that the group contains three elements, ${e=x^0, x, x^2}$, but I don't see how any of those elements can be the inverses of each other. If the group operation was multiplication, then the group elements would be ${e, x, \frac 1x, x^2, \sqrt x}$, making it of order 5. Now, in the trivial identity group, these inverses would not be present, meaning $a^{-1} \in H \ \forall a \in G$ would be untrue.

Comment: There's a typo in your definition. You mean $ab^{-1}\in H$ I think.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven No, I am aware that $ab{-1} \in H$ means that *a* and *b* are equivalent. I'm trying to understand why the equivalence between *a* and *b* exists when $ab{-1} \in H$, but not when $ab \in H$. I don't see how the proofs in my post are invalid, which is the problem.

Comment: The original worked because $a\equiv a$ meant $aa^{-1}\in H$, which it always does as it's the identity. In the new definition, $a\equiv a$ means $aa\in H$, and if $H$ does not have index $2$ in $G$, this isn't normally true for all $a$. Thus there exist elements that are not equivalent to themselves.

Comment: I am afraid  the final paragraph of your post (headed "Edit") is just nonsense, in its literal meaning of meaning of not making any sense at all. The beginning of the first sentence, "for an equivalence relation between $a$ and $b$ to be reflexive" simply does not make sense. What does a relation between $a$ and $b$ mean. We are talking about a relation on a set.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven But doesn't the closure law mean that if $a \in H \iff a^2 \in H$?

Comment: @ChemLad No. If $a\in H$ then $a^2\in H$. But if $a^2=e$ and $H=\{e\}$, why should $a=e$? Also, we are specifically thinking about elements of $G$ such that $a^2\not\in H$, so also $a\not\in H$. For example, take $H=\{e\}$. If your group has elements $a$ that don't satisfy $a^2=e$, then $a\not\equiv a\bmod \{e\}$.

Comment: @ChemLad: "How  is it true then that when $ab^{-1}\in H\implies $a^{-1}\in H\forall a\in G$".... **No.** It does not impy that, it is **not true**. I thought we had already gone through that in your other post. The **product** is in $H$. that does **not** mean that either factor is in $H$. They may be, or they may fail to be. We also already went through your continued misunderstanding about products. $a\in H$ implies $a^2\in H$. $a^2\in H$ **does not** imply $a\in H$. In the integers, twice any integer is even. Does that mean that every integer is even?

Answer (score 4):

There is very little in this post that makes any sense. It seems to be utterly confused as to what it means for a binary relation to be an equivalence relation, let alone facts about groups.

Remember: given any **set** $S$, a binary relation $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $S$ if and only if three things happen:

1. For every $s\in S$, $s\sim s$; every element is related to itself.
2. For every $s,t\in S$, if $s\sim t$ (if $s$ is related to $t$), then $t\sim s$ (then $t$ is related to $s$).
3. For every $s,t,v\in S$, if $s\sim t$ and $t\sim v$ (if $s$ is related to $t$ and $t$ is related to $v$) then $s\sim v$ (then $s$ is related to $v$).

We say the relation is reflexive if it satisfies (1); symmetric if it satisfies (2); and transitive if it satisfies (3).

Now, you are proposing a relation on the elements of $G$ (relative to a given fixed subgroup $H$) defined as follows:
$$ a\sim b\iff ab\in H.$$
Now, this is a perfectly fine binary relation on elements of $G$. The question is whether it is, generally, an equivalence relation. (Spoiler: no, it almost never is).

What would it mean for this relation to be reflexive? We would need to show that for every $g\in G$, $g\sim g$ holds. When does $g\sim g$ hold? When $gg=g^2\in H$. That is:
$$g\sim g\iff g^2\in H.$$
So in order to prove that this relation is reflexive, you would need to show that the square of every element is in $H$. You did nothing anywhere near this. Your argument is nonsensical, in the sense that it literally makes no sense. Picking $a,e\in G$... why? Reflexivity is about a single element. And what does it matter that $aa^{-1}\in H$? That product is not one that we care about in this relation. Your argument could be used to show that for every $g\in G$ we have $g\sim g^{-1}$ (every element is related to its inverse), but that is not what we need to show, so there is little point to showing it in this case. There are, of course, plenty of subgroups of a group that do not contain every square, so in general this relation will not be reflexive. It is reflexive if and only if $G^2=\langle g^2\mid g\in G\rangle\leq H$.

What would we need for this relation to be symmetric? We would need to show that if $a\sim b$ holds, then $b\sim a$ holds. So we would need to show that **if** we know that $ab\in H$, *then* it will follow that $ba\in H$. Now you correctly note that if $ab\in H$ then $(ab)^2\in H$. But then you make a computation, $a^{-1}(ab)^2b^{-1}$ that makes absolutely no sense, and for which you have absolutely no warrant to think it will lie in $H$. Multiplying an element of $H$, namely $ab$, by something that *you do not know whether it lies in $H$ or not* (namely, $a^{-1}$) tells you absolutely nothing about whether it is in $H$ or not. In fact, the only way you can guarantee that $a^{-1}(ab)b^{-1}$ lies in $H$ is if you know that both $a$ and $b$ lie in $H$... and you most certainly do not.

I already gave you, elsewhere, an explicit example of a case in which you have $H\leq G$, elements $a,b\in G$, such that $ab\in H$ but $ba\notin H$. Namely, take $G=S_3$, $H=\{ e,(12)\}$, and $a=(123)$, $b=(23)$. Then $ab=(123)(23)=(12)\in H$, but $ba=(23)(123) = (13)\notin H$. (I compose my permutations right-to-left). So this condition will not hold in general either.

As for transitivity, what we need to show is that if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ (that is, if we already know that $ab$ and $bc$ both are in $H$), then $a\sim c$ (then $ac\in H$). Again, you did not do anything related to this. Instead, you considered $(ab)b^{-2}(bc)$. While the two outside factors lie in $H$, the middle factor does not, in general, lie in $H$, so you do not know whether this product lies in $H$. Thus, your argument fails again for the same reason as your other arguments: you seem to think that you can just multiply by whatever you want and the result will be in $H$. *That is simply not the case.*

I strongly urge you to write out exactly what you need to prove, then translate it into their group theory meaning, and then try to prove them carefully. Your telegraphic method here makes it impossible to tell exactly where your errors come from, other than from a general misunderstanding of how groups work.

---

We might note that if $G^2\leq H$, then this relation is identical as a relation to the usual one,
$$a\equiv b\iff ab^{-1}\in H;$$
identical in the sense that $a\sim b\iff a\equiv b$. Indeed, under the general assumption that every square is in $H$, we have that $ab\in H$ if and only if $ab^{-1}=(ab)(b^{-1})^2\in H$.

Since the condition that $G^2\leq H$ is necessary in order for this relation to be reflexive, it follows that this relation is an equivalence relation on $G$ if and only if $G^2\leq H$ if and only if this is just the usual relation "equivalent modulo $H$ on the right" in disguise.

Comment: According to the linked site, $ab^{-1} \in H \iff a \in H$, because if not, $aa^{-1} \notin H$, meaning $a \equiv a$ is untrue, which means $a \equiv b$ is untrue, meaning $ab^{-1} \notin H$. So, if $ab^{-1} \in H \iff a ~ b$, then that necessitates that $a \in H$. But we only know that $ab^{-1}, a^{-1}b, e \in H$, as well as any power of those elements. So, how can we say that $a \in H$, isnt that the same assumption that I made?

Comment: @ChemLad: I see **nowhere** on the "linked site" that claims that $ab^{-1}\in H$ is equivalent to $a\in H$. In fact, **nowhere** in the linked site is there even an $\iff$ symbol. All the implications in that site are one-directional. Your "explanation" in the comment is false where it not utter nonsense. You are making wild, incoherent, false assertions all over the place. Let me put it simply: you have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: @ChemLad: And if you are going to use a website to try to learn the material, try to find one that at least doesn't mispell the word "congruence".

Comment: I just realized I made the same assumption again. $e \in H$, because H has to have an identity. Now, $e = gg^{-1} \ \forall g \in G$. which includes *a*. I thought that since $aa^{-1} \in H$, that meant $a \in H$, hence the above statement. For some reason, my brain has had a hard time kicking the idea that just because a product exists in a group, it doesn't mean the composing factors exist in that group.

Comment: The first article was far better than the last, without any typos (as far as I could see). The follow-up article seems to be written by someone else, because it was IMO less clear and it had many typos.

Comment: @ChemLad: It's way more than that; you are carelessly reading pages on the web (pages that aren't even that good to begin with). As I said: there is **nowhere** on that page that the bidirectional $\iff$ even *appears*. Given how much difficulty you are having with these concepts, you really should be paying close attention to what you are reading... and you simply are not. You keep repeating the same error over and over and over and over, and you keep misreading statements over and over and over. You need to take a step back and review the *basics* of groups before continuing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $a^x \equiv b^y \iff a^xa^y \land b^yb^x$?

Comment: @ChemLad That doesn't make sense at all. Your right hand side just names two elements with a logical connective. What you wrote is not even a well-formed formula: it is literal nonsense. So, no, you do not understand correctly. It is patently clear that you lack the necessary foundation to be trying to understand these basic ideas. You need to go back and learn about groups and subgroups *properly* before attempting to continue.

Comment: I used the bidirectional arrow because I thought that if $a \equiv b$, it had to be because $ab^{-1} \in H$. Isn't that the case? How can they be equivalent to each other without $ab^{-1} \in H$?

Comment: @ChemLad: So... because the bidirectional arrow is used in one statement (that $a\equiv b\pmod{H}$ is equivalent, *by definition* to $ab^{-1}\in H$), then it follows that the bidirectional arrow should be used *always*, in any statement? Again:  what you wrote was that "$a^x\equiv b^y\iff a^xa^y\wedge b^yb^x$". Literally: "$a$ to the $x$ is equivalent to $b$ to the $y$ if and only if $a$ to the $x$ $a$ to the $y$ and $b$ to the $y$ $b$ to the $x$." Everything after "if and only if" is nonsense. You don't seem to understand what you read or what you write.

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote it. It's $a^x \equiv b^y \pmod G \iff a^xa^y, b^yb^x \in G$

Comment: @ChemLad: And what you now write is also false. $a^x\equiv b^y\pmod{G}$ if and only if $a^x(b^y)^{-1}\in G$ (assuming congruence on the right). That is not the same thing as the assertion that $a^xa^y$ lies in $G$, or that $b^yb^x$ lies in $G$. (Absent context, $G$ is a *subgroup* of some overgroup). That's **not true**. You are utterly and completely lost, and you need to stop. I am being blunt because the gentle approach clearly failed over the past couple of days.

Comment: Where did you get the exponent $-1$?

Comment: @ChemLad: *From the definition of congruence*.

Comment: Sorry again, I misformulated myself again. Here is my last attempt: $a^xb^y \in G \land a \equiv b \iff a^xa^y, b^yb^x \in G$.

Comment: @ChemLad: I'm out. You can't seem to write what you mean, I'm not going to go back and forth with you a hundred times in comments until you manage to say what you mean (which will likely be false anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\{[0]_3\}=H\le G=\Bbb Z_3$. In order for your relation, call it $\sim$, to be an equivalence relation, we require $a\sim a$ for all $a\in G$ (reflexivity); but this means $a+_3a=2a\in H$ for all $a\in G$, and yet

$$\begin{align}
[1]_3+_3[1]_3&=[1+1]_3\\
&=[2]_3\\
&\neq [0]_3,
\end{align}$$

where

$$[x]_3=\{ y\in\Bbb Z\, :\, 3\mid x-y\}.$$

---

What *is* an equivalence relation, though, for a general group $G$, is

$$a\sim_Hb\iff ab^{-1}\in H,$$

for all $a,b\in G$ and $H\le G$.